# power of mann-whitney test

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I've written in last post about two groups of data (case-disease) that need to be compare. This time I don't have binary data but variable data. Example below:

```
Sample bacteria1 bacteria2 bacteria3
s1 0.5 0.7 0.1
s2 0.03 0.02 0.9
s3 ...
```

I have 100 samples with disease and 100 samples as control.

To compare the differences between 2 groups (case-control) I've decided to use Mann-Whitney test. 
But first I would like to predict the sample size for this test with power=0.8 and alpha=0.05.
Do you know how can I do that? Is there a tool that can calculate the required sample size for experiment for Mann-Whitney test?

Thanks in advance!
Agata

Comment: Which effect size do you want to detect (in terms of $P(X_{case}>X_{control})$)?

Comment: Not sure yet, I would like to try different options and fit it to my experiment.

Comment: It is only possible to compute sample size once you have defined the minimum effect size you want to detect. It takes huge samples to detect tiny differences; smaller samples to detect huge differences.

Comment: Let's say Cohen medium = 0.5